# Replacement for textureCube in GLSL 150+?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I am wondering what the replacement for this function is. Do I simply call "texture" in as a replacement for this function call? Or is there a new way of doing this unlike 120 and before?

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
uniform samplerCube sampler;

[...]

fragColor = texture(sampler, centroi.xyz) * (ambient + specular + diffuse);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this is yes. The textureCube function has been deprecated because they have created an overload in texture() that does the same thing. I guess this is a good way to unify everything into one call.

I'll leave this up just in case anyone else is looking for this!